# Variable in array (returning null)

Tags: php, arrays, variables, syntax

I cannot seem to be able to use the variable into the array. It must be a syntax error.

Please, help me sort this out.

```
$id=$_POST['eventid'];
$data = array('message' => $id);
```

$id content is null.

Thanks.

Comment: what does var_dump($_POST); give you?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` will do some magic

Comment: If `$_POST` doesn't have an entry `eventid`, then `$id` will be `null`. That's not a syntax problem, it's a data problem. You have to send the correct data.

Comment: If you can add the form elements in your code

Comment: @user1581579 check $_POST  have any value for eventid by print_r($_POST).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coding is nice except the `$_POST` value is not getting fetched. I have commented the `POST` var just to make sure your code works fine.

```
<?php

$id='test';//$_POST['eventid'];
$data = array('message' => $id);

print_r($data);//output : Array ( [message] => test )
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump` should always to be used for debug purposes, I think.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo, true. I am just illustrating OP with `print_r` so it can be somewhat readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_POST['eventid'];
$data = array('message' => $id);
```

If $id is null, it means that $_POST['eventid'] is null.

Also, are you sure that it is actually null, and not a blank string? Because there's a slight difference between the two.

My guess is that $_POST['eventid'] does not exist or the value is an empty string.